# How to flatten the nested array of of objects and duplicate the parent

Tags: javascript, arrays, flatten, ramda.js

I have an array of objects that has one of the properties(`"attributes"`) as array of objects.

```
var products = [
    {
        "productId": "1",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "variant":"red",
                "price": "134.00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "productId": "2",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "variant": "green",
                "value": "3400.00"
            },
            {
                "variant": "pink",
                "price": "342.00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want the nested array of objects to be flattened and copied onto parent but the parent object needs to be duplicated for each of the nested object. (Not sure if I have explained it correctly).

The converted array of objects should be:

```
var transformedProducts = [
    {
        "productId": "1",
        "variant":"red",
        "price": "134.00"
    },
    {
        "productId": "2",
        "variant": "green",
        "value": "3400.00"
    },
    {
        "productId": "2",
        "variant": "pink",
        "price": "342.00"
    }
]
```

I can map over the outer array and then again map over the inner array, and in the inner most map, construct a new object.
Is there a better or more functional approach to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Array.flatMap()` to iterate the objects, and then iterate the `attributes` with `Array.map()`, and combine with the rest of the object. The `Array.flatMap()` would also flatten the array of arrays to a single array.

```js
const fn = arr => arr.flatMap(({ attributes, ...rest }) => 
  attributes.map(o => ({
    ...rest,
    ...o
  }))
)

const products = [{"productId":"1","attributes":[{"variant":"red","price":"134.00"}]},{"productId":"2","attributes":[{"variant":"green","value":"3400.00"},{"variant":"pink","price":"342.00"}]}]

const result = fn(products)

console.log(result)
```

With Ramda, you can iterate and flatten the array using `R.chain`. To get an array of attributes combined with their parents, you can use the `R.ap` as combinator of two functions:

1. Extracts the attributes array, and then applies it to the 2nd function.
2. Gets the rest of the object (without the attributes), and creates a mapping function that merges it to the iterated objects.

```js
const { chain, ap, pipe, prop, applyTo, omit, mergeRight, map } = R

const fn = chain(ap(
  pipe(prop('attributes'), applyTo),
  pipe(omit(['attributes']), mergeRight, map)
))

const products = [{"productId":"1","attributes":[{"variant":"red","price":"134.00"}]},{"productId":"2","attributes":[{"variant":"green","value":"3400.00"},{"variant":"pink","price":"342.00"}]}]

const result = fn(products)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) as follows:

```js
const products = [ { "productId": "1", "attributes": [ { "variant":"red", "price": "134.00" } ] }, { "productId": "2", "attributes": [ { "variant": "green", "value": "3400.00" }, { "variant": "pink", "price": "342.00" } ] } ];

const output = products.map(({productId,attributes}) => 
    attributes.map(({variant,price}) => ({productId,variant,price}))
)
.flat();

console.log( output );
```

Or to only name `attributes`, in case there are other properties:

```js
const products = [ { "productId": "1", "attributes": [ { "variant":"red", "price": "134.00" } ] }, { "productId": "2", "attributes": [ { "variant": "green", "value": "3400.00" }, { "variant": "pink", "price": "342.00" } ] } ];

const output = products.map(({attributes,...rest}) => 
    attributes.map(attribute => ({...rest,...attribute}))
)
.flat();

console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you:

```
const transformedProducts = [];

products.forEach((product) => {
    product.attributes.forEach((attribute) => {
        transformedProducts.push({
            productId: product.productId,
            ...attribute,
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what I did. Wondering if there are any better ways than nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my array is having objects with in objects there are child array. I wanted a single array with all child objects

So I used this function to get all objects in a single array

```
  let array = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 't1',
        sort_order: 200,
        childs: [
          {
            id: 2,
            title: 't2',
            sort_order: 200,
            childs: [],
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            title: 'mytitle',
            sort_order: 200,
            childs: [],
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            title: 'mytitle',
            sort_order: 200,
            childs: [],
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            title: 'mytitle',
            sort_order: 200,
            childs: [],
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            title: 'mytitle',
            sort_order: 200,
            childs: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        title: 'راهنما',
        sort_order: 'mytitle',
        childs: [
          {
            id: 8,
            title: 'mytitle',
            sort_order: 200,
            childs: [],
          },
          {
            id: 9,
            title: 'mytitle',
            sort_order: 200,
            childs: [],
          },
          {
            id: 10,
            title: 'mytitle',
            sort_order: 200,
            childs: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
```

here is my code

```
let flattenArray = [];

function flatten(a) {
  flattenArray.push(a);
  if (a.childs?.length) a.childs.map(flatten);
}

array?.map((el) => {
  flattenArray.push(el);
  if (el.childs?.length) el.childs.map(flatten);
});

console.log(flattenArray);
```

results :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "t1",
        "sort_order": 200,
        "childs": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "t2",
                "sort_order": 200,
                "childs": []
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "mytitle",
                "sort_order": 200,
                "childs": []
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "title": "mytitle",
                "sort_order": 200,
                "childs": []
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "title": "mytitle",
                "sort_order": 200,
                "childs": []
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "title": "mytitle",
                "sort_order": 200,
                "childs": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "t2",
        "sort_order": 200,
        "childs": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "mytitle",
        "sort_order": 200,
        "childs": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "mytitle",
        "sort_order": 200,
        "childs": []
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "mytitle",
        "sort_order": 200,
        "childs": []
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "mytitle",
        "sort_order": 200,
        "childs": []
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "راهنما",
        "sort_order": "mytitle",
        "childs": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "title": "mytitle",
                "sort_order": 200,
                "childs": []
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "title": "mytitle",
                "sort_order": 200,
                "childs": []
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "title": "mytitle",
                "sort_order": 200,
                "childs": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "title": "mytitle",
        "sort_order": 200,
        "childs": []
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "mytitle",
        "sort_order": 200,
        "childs": []
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "title": "mytitle",
        "sort_order": 200,
        "childs": []
    }
]
```